# Large amount text fields for form, solutions needed

Tags: html, ios, ios5, mailto, xcode4.3

My quest to to understand how to get data from a text field to email has so far got me nowhere so im now trying a different approach (a workaround to be more precise).  I have created a form in HTML, im using the mailto function because this is the only way I can seem to get any data of the iphone to email. My next problem is that because there are appox 300 text fields in total it makes this a very long page.  Also, with the email button at the bottom of this html page it creates an annoyance for the user.  In some instances only perhaps 4 of the text fields will be used meaning this will be a huge long email for four text boxes . Is there any way i can break it up in to manageable chunks, or dynamically add the text fields as much as the user needs? I realise that the ideal solution would be to do all this properly  but its just out of my skills base. I have tried incorporating some controls from cocoa controls for this  but couldn't understand how to get that working in my project, hence the use of mailto as a final resort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear, but I'll try to answer. Maybe you should pay attention on the trick like in LiveJournal(line on the bottom of the page).

```
.buttonClass {
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -0.5*buttonWidth;
 postion: fixed;
 bottom: buttonHeight;
}
```

In that case your button will be fixed at be the bottom of the page and user could scroll as much as he wants.

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear and thanks for your advice. My button is fixed at the bottom of the page, thats the problem, with 300 or so fields at its maximum, its a looong scrol to the bottom.